# Bourbon/Neat Grid 2.0 shift issue

Tags: css, sass, neat

I have a custom neat grid 2.0 grid where I want to push the columns to different areas depending on screen size. For instance, on mobile, the footer-submit is stacked 1st. On desktop it's pushed to the far right side of the screen.  What I have works as expected except their calculation may be slightly off. But I'm still getting the hang of this grid so maybe I am implementing weirdly.

```
$no-gutter-grid: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 0,
);

footer {
  @include grid-container;
}

.footer-nav {
  @include grid-column(12, $no-gutter-grid);
  @include grid-media($grid-tablet-up) {
    @include grid-column(10, $no-gutter-grid);
    @include grid-shift(-2);
  }
  color: $white;
  nav {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}

.footer-submit {
  @include grid-column(12, $no-gutter-grid);
  @include grid-media($grid-tablet-up) {
    @include grid-column(2, $no-gutter-grid);
    @include grid-shift(10);
  }
}
```

And my html:

```
<footer>
  <div class="newsletter">
    <div>
      <p>Subscribe to our newsletter</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <button class="button-black" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-submit">
      <a href="#" class="button-orange">Submit A Story</a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-nav">
      <nav>
        <a href="/" class="logo-link"><img class="logo" src="{% static 'img/SAHARA_LOGO_OFFICIALS_WHITE.png' %}"></a>
        <!--TODO change to dynamic links-->
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#">Careers</a>
        <a href="#">Support Us</a>
        <a href="#">Advertise</a>
        <a href="#">NewsSources</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="legal">
        <p>&#169;Copyright 2017 Sahara Reporters, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <span>
          <a href="#">Privacy Policiy</a> /
          <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
        </span>


      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

[image: As you can see the buttons aren't lining up. If I do this grid normally with no push, they line up perfectly.]

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I understand, you have a submit button stacked on top of a navigation while on desktop. When the user hits tablet you want the submit button to be to the right of the navigation.

If thats the case you're gonna want to use the `direction` property in the custom grid. It would look something like this:

```
$no-gutter-grid_tablet: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 0,
  direction: rtl,
);

$no-gutter-grid: (
  columns: 12,
  gutter: 0,
);

footer {
  @include grid-container;
}

.footer-nav {
  @include grid-column(12, $no-gutter-grid);
  @include grid-media($grid-tablet-up) {
    @include grid-column(10, $no-gutter-grid_tablet);
  }
  color: $white;
  nav {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}

.footer-submit {
  @include grid-column(12, $no-gutter-grid);
  @include grid-media($grid-tablet-up) {
    @include grid-column(2, $no-gutter-grid_tablet);
  }
}
```

Now that your going right to left you dont have to shift anything. Instead it is just going to reverse the order in which the divs are displayed.

Hope this helps!